# Angular-material md-virtual-repeat I get the same count of watchers, why?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I try to understand [md-virtual-repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat) purpose and for some reason I don't see the difference with single `md-list` and `ng-repeat`.

> Virtual repeat is a limited substitute for ng-repeat that renders only
>   enough dom nodes to fill the container and recycling them as the user
>   scrolls. Arrays, but not objects are supported for iteration.

I have huge list of items and I use Chrome watcher count to see the improvements.

Before I used `ng-repeat` and I got ~4000 of watchers. However when I migrated to `md-virtual-repeat` I got the same 4K of watchers.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
      <div md-virtual-repeat="agenda in ctrl.items"  >
         <span ng-if="::agenda.isDivider" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                        <span>
                            {{agenda.title.day}}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            {{agenda.title.date}}
                        </span>
                    </span>


                    <div ng-if="::!agenda.isDivider"  
                          flex layout="row" layout-align="start center">
                       ...
                   </div>
```

do I miss something?

This is an example I play with: [Codepan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKaNeN?editors=1010)

Comment: Perhaps it only relates to the dom elements (how heavy the view gets), while the watchers are on the items themselves, just a wild guess and apologize in advance.

Comment: @AlexMounir  each item has 2 buttons and several text fields, so item has at least 4 watchers. But it's not the meeter. virtual repeat should reduce DOM elements to visible count, therefore less watchers.

Comment: @snaggs What is the height of your virtual-repeat-container? Also how many of your divs have a ng-if=true vs ng-if=false?